# Rowmax as new column in data table

Tags: dataset, stata

I have rank scores of countries for different variables.

I would like to create a column with the maximum rank that occurs per row.

Say the data look something like:

```
    A B C D E F G H I .... 
V1  1 4 5 3 12 . 6 9 83
V2  . . 4 6 1 4  7 6 32
```

So A - X are countries. In rows V1 up you have various variables and in the cells you have the rank score relating to the variable.

Problem is that some countries for whatever reasons don´t score in relation to certain variables, perhaps because V1 is not relevant to country C or whatever.

So in the end I´d like something like

```
A B C D E F G H I ....   newv
V1  1 4 5 3 12 . 6 9 83  83
V2  . . 4 6 1 4  7 6 5    6
```

Comment: Translation: in Stata columns are strictly called variables and rows are called observations (and not variables). The data table is the dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `egen newvar=rowmax(A B C D E F G H I…)` does what you need. Have a look at the `egen` help file for more information. (I presume you need value 7 in the second row, not 6?)

Comment: yes. thanks a lot. problem why it did not work for me before was because my rank scores were in string form, after destring, replace and then your egen rowmax command it worked!